# I can not activate virtual enviroment

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I am using Windows. I created a virtual enviroment using Ananconda Prompt

```
conda create -n retinanet python=3.7 anaconda
```

I ran this command in

```
<base> C:\Users\mustafa>
```

Then, when I try to activate it

```
C:\Users\mustafa\Anaconda3\envs\retinanet\Scripts\activate
```

I see this error message:

```
'C:\Users\mustafa\Anaconda3\envs\retinanet\Scripts\activate' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable or batch file
```

Edit: I solved the problem by adding `..\..\activate.bat`

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? Also, when you try to activate it, are you passing that entire thing as the command?

Comment: Windows. Yes I pass the entire directory..

Comment: On Windows you should add the extension `..\..\activate.bat`

Comment: `conda activate retinanet`

Comment: Why are you trying to activate the environment like that? Have you not read the Conda docs?